# Put Space Between Auto-Generated Getters / Setters in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, methods, setter, space, getter

I am using Eclipse EE IDE - Indigo.  I filled in all my class variables and then right click on the page and select -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters.  This works fine but it puts the methods right on top of each other ex:

```
public String getValue1() {  
    return value1;  
}  
public void setValue1(String value1) {  
    $this.value1 = value1  
}  
public String getValue2() {  
    return value2;  
}  
public void setValue2(String value2) {  
    $this.value2 = value2
}
```

Is there any way to tell Eclipse to put a space between the methods when auto-generating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Empty line between generated getter/setter method is depending on presence of empty line between properties itselt.

So if I select this :

```
    private int foo;
    private int bar;
```

there will be no space between getters/setters, but if I select this :

```
    private int foo;

    private int bar;
```

there will be one empty line between methods.

Comment: I find it very odd that Eclipse assumes a relation between empty lines in my fields any empty lines in my getters/setters. While I **always** want an empty line between methods, I don't necessarily want it between fields.

Answer (score 20):

After the getters and setters have been created, select the newly created methods and "format" the code (Ctrl+Shift+F).

Comment: This solution is extremely straight forward, fast, and easy to use! Tested in Eclipse Juno.

Comment: It's funny though that Eclipse doesn't follow its own formatting rules when creating the getters and setters, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have fields like this:

```
private int first;
private int second;
private int third;
```

If you are going to add your getters and setters after the third field, leave a space between second and third fields, like this:

```
private int first;
private int second;

private int third;
```

Now you are good to go. Generate it and then remove the empty line you added.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  I tried this on Eclipse 3.7.  It's a bit clunky, but it works.

- Generate **one** getter or setter method using the right click option Source -> Generate Getters and Setters.
- Manually add two blank lines after the method.
- On the second blank line, use the right click option Source -> Generate Getters and Setters to generate the rest of the getters and setters.